# Sweet alert success button ERROR using an Script

Tags: javascript, php

I've been trying to use this script called "Sweet alert" in my form because I want my site with a nice look. 
The thing is that when I want to login, my document called validar.php recognize user and password normally but it doesn't redirect to other page.

I've already added these "Sweet alert" libreries at the beggining of my program.

```
 if($f3=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql3))
    {
        if($pass==$f2['contraAdmin'] && $administrador==$f3['tipoUsuario'])
        {
        echo "<script>
            swal({  
                title: 'Acceso',
                text: '¡Bienvenido Administrador!',  
                type: 'success',    
                confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar', 
                showLoaderOnConfirm: true, }, 
                    function(){      
                        location.href = 'RegistroEmp.php';  

                 });
            </script>";


        }
```

Therefore, when I use an script alert it works perfectly.

```
 echo '<script>alert("Welcome Admin")</script> ';

            echo "<script>location.href='RegistroEmp.php'</script>";
```

Thanks. 
I hope you can help me. 
Regards!

Comment: do you get any errors in the browser console?

Comment: No, It appears the new message but when I clicked in the button "accept"
 
              confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar'

The browser doesn't show anything, 
It just have this URL: "http://localhost/CASA/validar.php" instead of this one:
http://localhost/CASA/RegistroEmp.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be useful

```
swal({
  title: 'Acceso',
  text: "¡Bienvenido Administrador!",
  type: 'success',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar'
}).then(function(){
    location.href='RegistroEmp.php'
})
```